# function .. takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, oop

I am new to Python and I want to practice a parent and derived class. I want to call parent function to the child class using super. But I got some error. Code is

```
class First:
    def my_func():
        print('first')

class Second(First):
    def my_func1():
        super().my_func()
        print('second')

obj = Second()
obj.my_func1()
```

Comment: 1) change `def my_func():` to `def my_func(self):`

Comment: 2) change `def my_func1():` to `def my_func1(self):`

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self

Answer (score 2):

```
class First:
    def my_func(self):
        print('first')

class Second(First):
    def my_func1(self):
        super().my_func()
        print('second')

obj = Second()
obj.my_func1()
```